# Android popper navigation with Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment, android-architecture-navigation

I have two fragments **FirstFragment** and **WelcomeFragment** ,

in **FirstFragment** i have some animation and i load data from server then i navigate to **WelcomeFragment** using NavController :

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_welcomeFragment);
```

and my nav_graph is like this :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.flyeducation.UI.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_welcomeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/welcomeFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out" />
    </fragment>
```

i want ot have this behaviour :

> **navigating from FirstFragment to WelcomeFragment but not having the ability to go back to FirstFragment when pressing the back button the
>   app should close like pressing the home Button and when coming back staying in the WelcomeFragment**

from the documentation i tried in the nav_graph XML :

```
app:popUpTo="@id/firstFragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

the app closes but when i go back to it , it does start all over again from the FirstFragment and not maintaining the state that i want which is staying in WelcomeFragment

from other questions i also tried this in WelcomeFragment :

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.firstFragment, true);
```

Anyone can help me achieving the wanted behaviour

**EDIT :**

I ended up intercepting the onKeyDown and also Simulating Home click when it onKeyDown is pressed on my **WelcomeFragment**

This in my **WelcomeFragment**

```
public void myOnKeyDown(int key_code, Context context){
        openDialog(context);
    }

    public void openDialog(final Context context) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Exit ! ")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you wanna quit our App , we will miss you !")
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null) // dismisses by default
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                            context.startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
```

and this in my **Activity** :

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        ((WelcomeFragment) WelcomeFragment).myOnKeyDown(keyCode, this);
        return false ;
    }
```

> **This has give me the behaviour i want but i do not think it is best practice**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the right solution to be used in my case , it will have the same behaviour described in the question and like what i had when overriding `onKeyDown` in `MainActivity`

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                openDialog(getContext());
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), callback);
```

Another clue :

```
app:popUpTo="@id/fragment"
```

is used when the fragment is in the back stack

and

```
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

will clear the stack untill hitting the fragment id in `app:popUpTo`

described here [popUpTo and popUpToInclusive](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop)

Answer (score 1):

You should never be popping the start destination of your graph. As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination):

> Note: An app might have a one-time setup or series of login screens. These [conditional screens](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-conditional) should not be considered start destinations because users see these screens only in certain cases.

You should instead follow the [first time user experience documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#first-time_user_experience) to redirect users from your `WelcomeFragment` to your `FirstFragment` only in the cases where the user has not already gone to the through that screen.

By following this setup, the 99% of the time users get a faster experience (they only load one fragment), the `NavigationUI` helpers that rely on your `startDestination` work correctly, and [deep links](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link) will also work correctly.

Comment: I went to the liks and read them briefly , for my case FirstFragment is always my first page because i load data from the server in that fragment and WelcomeFragment is where i check if the user is AUTHENTICATED or not

Comment: @waghydjemy - those don't sound like a fixed start destination that the user sees when they are already logged in. That seems exactly like what should be done conditionally.

Comment: The links provieded in your question were really helpfull , but i am not following those navigation logic in my application i have my own , Thank you a lot